# 2 table in 1 Column

Tags: mysql, join

I need a query to Join 2 tables in 1 column

something like:

SELECT name_cat, name_dog FROM cat, dog;

my results in 1 column

```
+-------------+
| name_animal |
+-------------+
| cat_1       |
| dog_1       |
| cat_2       |
| cat_3       |
| dog_2       |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using `UNION`. Considering the same example, the query should be:

```
mysql> SELECT `name_cat` FROM `cat` UNION SELECT `name_dog` FROM `dog`;
+---------------+
| `name_cat`    |
+---------------+
| cat_1         |
| dog_1         |
| cat_2         |
| cat_3         |
| dog_2         |
+---------------+
```

The example is given here:

```
mysql> SELECT REPEAT('a',1) UNION SELECT REPEAT('b',10);
+---------------+
| REPEAT('a',1) |
+---------------+
| a             |
| bbbbbbbbbb    |
+---------------+
```

Hope this helps. :)